Max cut 2-approximation algorithm
Given an undirected unweighted graph $G$, we'll define $f(G)$ as the maximum number of edges crossing a cut in $G$. Find a (polynomial) 2-approximation for $f$.
I know about the probabilistic method, but I'm trying to find a non-probabilistic way to solve it.
I thought about the following algorithm:

Start with $S=V, \overline{S}=\emptyset$.
For every $v\in S$:
If removing $v$ from $S$ increase the number of crossing edges, then remove it
At the end the loop, return number of edges crossing $S$.

I believe this algorithm to be the answer, but got stuck on proving it.
I want to say that at the end of the loop, for all $v\in V$, the amount of connected edges that cross the cut is bigger or equal to amount of connected edges that do not.
This will immediately show the lower bound.
But I don't think I can say that, since this quality is true for $v_k$ in the kth iteration, but it can become false in the following iterations (since we can remove other vertices in those iterations).

In Handbook of Approximation Algorithms and Metaheuristics (Khuller, Raghavachari, Young), in chapter 4, part 4.10, the authors describe a method to derandomize the usual probabilistic algorithm.
The idea to create $S$ is to browse each vertex $(v_1, …, v_n)$ and decide if $v_i$ is added to $S$ or not, depending on the expected value of crossing edges among remaining edges.
Let us denote:

$V_i := \{v_1, …, v_i\}$,
$S_i := S\cap V_i$ (the vertices up to the $i$-th chosen to be in $S$),
$T_i := V_i\setminus S_i$ (the vertices up to the $i$-th chosen NOT to be in $S$),
$c_i$ the number of edges from $S_i$ to $T_i$ and
$e_i$ the number of edges which are still not known to be crossing the cut or not (meaning at least one of its extremities is in $V\setminus V_i$).

At step $i$, if we continue the choices at random, the expected value of crossing edges is $x_i := c_i + \frac{e_i}2$. We will make the $i+1$-th choice to guarantee that $x_i \leqslant x_{i+1}$:

if $v_{i+1}$ is added to $S$, then $c_{i+1} = c_i + |N(v_{i+1})\cap T_i| - |N(v_{i+1})\cap S_i|$;
if $v_{i+1}$ is not added to $S$, then $c_{i+1} = c_i + |N(v_{i+1})\cap S_i| - |N(v_{i+1})\cap T_i|$.

In both cases, $x_{i+1} - x_i = \dfrac{c_{i+1}-c_i}2$. We can choose deterministically $x_i\leqslant x_{i+1}$ depending on the value of $|N(v_{i+1})\cap T_i| - |N(v_{i+1})\cap S_i|$.
Since $\dfrac12 = x_0 \leqslant x_1 \leqslant … \leqslant x_n$ and $x_n$ is the size of the cut, we guarantee that this is a $\frac12$-approximation.

As you said, itratively select a vertex $v$ from $S$ or $S^-$ for which moving to other set improves CUT number. Therefore, the algorithm terminates after at most $z^*(cut)$ iterations. At the end, for $v\in S:$ $d_v^S \leq d_v^{S^-}$; Since, moving $v$ from $S$ to $S^-$ does not improve the CUT. Hence, the CUT (the edges $d_v^{S^-}$) includes more than half of the edges adjacent to $v$. Similarly, for $v\in S^-:$ $d_v^S 
\geq d_v^{S^-}$; Hence, the CUT includes more than half of the edges adjacent to $v$. Therefore. the final CUT $\geq 0.5\mid E \mid$ $\geq $ 0.5(optimal CUT).
